# Logstash workers sky rocket to 100% CPU

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a problem on `logstash` where my workers jump to 100% CPU while activating 1 specific filter. Im currently using this input + filter (on which grok parses ok):

```
input {
    redis {
        key => "logs_services_dyna_customer.lnxdev01"
        data_type => ['list']
        db => 8
        host => "kibana.test.local"
        type => "D_Customer"
        tags => ["d_local"]
        add_field => {
            server => "lnxdev01"
        }
        codec => "plain"
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] in ["D_Customer"] {
        mutate {
            gsub => ["message", "\r", ""]
        }
        grok {
          patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns/"
          match => ["message", "^Request Headers:\n(%{WORD:request_method} %{DATA:service_url} %{DATA}\n)?(Host: %{HOSTNAME:request_host}\n)?(Connection: %{WORD:request_connection}\n)?(User-Agent: %{DATA:user_agent}\n)?(Content-Type: %{DATA:content_type}\n)?(SOAPAction: \"%{DATA:request_action}\"\n)?(Content-Length: %{NUMBER:request_content_length}\n)?(Cookie: %{DATA}\n)?(:?X-START-DATE: %{APACHE_DATETIME:request_start_date})?\n+Request Body:\n%{GREEDIERDATA:request_body}\n+Response Headers:\n(HTTP/%{DATA}(?<response_code>\d{3}) %{DATA:response_message}\n)?(Cache-Control: %{DATA}\n)?(Content-Length: %{NUMBER:response_content_length}\n)?(Content-Type: %{DATA:response_content_type}\n)?(Server: %{DATA:response_server}\n)?(X-AspNet-Version: %{DATA}\n)?(X-Powered-By: %{DATA}\n)?(Date: %{APACHE_DATETIME:response_date}\n)?(Connection: %{WORD:response_connection}\n)?\n+Response Body:\n%{GREEDIERDATA:response_body}$"]
          add_field => ["category", "Service"]
        }
        date {
          match => ["request_start_date", "EEE, dd MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z"]
        }
        date {
          match => ["request_start_date", "EEE, dd MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z"]
          target => "request_start_date"
        }
        date {
          match => ["response_date", "EEE, dd MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss z"]
          target => "response_date"
        }
    }
}
```

And below the log itself:

```
Request Headers:
POST /Middleware.OIL.I01_SearchCustomer.Wcf/WcfService_Middleware_OIL_I01_SearchCustomer_App.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: w12vfdbiz101-t.dy.nl
Connection: close
User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/7.0.9-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "SearchCustomer"
Content-Length: 1628
X-START-DATE: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 13:27:03 UTC



Request Body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.dy.eu/Customer/V1-0"><SOAP-ENV:Body><v1:SearchCustomerRequest xmlns:v1="http://www.dy.eu/Customer/V1-0" xmlns:v2="http://dy/CoreComponents/Schemas/dy/V2-0" xmlns:urn="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:urn1="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:v21="http://dy/CoreComponents/Schemas/dy/V2-0">
  <v2:HeaderInfo>
    <v2:TransactionId>58208127a1179</v2:TransactionId>
    <v2:UserId>1</v2:UserId>
    <v2:ApplicationId>Omnius</v2:ApplicationId>
    <v2:PartyName>OGW</v2:PartyName>
  </v2:HeaderInfo>
  <v1:SearchedAccount>
    <urn:PartyName>
      <urn1:Name/>
    </urn:PartyName>
  </v1:SearchedAccount>
  <v1:SearchedContact>
    <v21:Role>
      <v21:Person>
        <urn1:ID/>
        <urn1:FirstName>Friedrich</urn1:FirstName>
        <urn1:FamilyName>Muller</urn1:FamilyName>
        <urn:Contact>
          <urn1:Telephone/>
          <urn1:ElectronicMail/>
        </urn:Contact>
        <urn:ResidenceAddress>
          <urn1:StreetName/>
          <urn1:BuildingNumber/>
          <urn1:CityName/>
          <urn1:PostalZone/>
        </urn:ResidenceAddress>
      </v21:Person>
    </v21:Role>
  </v1:SearchedContact>
  <v1:SearchedEquipment>
    <urn:ManufacturersItemIdentification>
      <urn1:ID/>
    </urn:ManufacturersItemIdentification>
  </v1:SearchedEquipment>
</v1:SearchCustomerRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>



Response Headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 2379
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 07 Nov 2016 13:27:10 GMT
Connection: close


Response Body:
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><ns0:SearchCustomerResponse xmlns:ns0="http://www.dy.eu/Customer/V1-0" xmlns:ns1="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:ns3="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns5="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDataTypes-2" xmlns:ns6="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:UnqualifiedDataTypes-2" xmlns:ns7="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:CoreComponentTypeSchemaModule:2" xmlns:ns8="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SignatureAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ns9="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" xmlns:ns10="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ns11="http://Dy/CoreComponents/Schemas/Dy/V2-0" xmlns:ns12="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonSignatureComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><cbc:ReferenceID>8</cbc:ReferenceID><ns10:Status xsi:type="ns10:StatusType"><cbc:StatusReasonCode/><cbc:StatusReason/></ns10:Status><ns11:Success>true</ns11:Success><ns0:ReturnedNumberOfRecords>1</ns0:ReturnedNumberOfRecords><ns11:Account><ns10:PartyName><cbc:Name>CompanyName_0</cbc:Name></ns10:PartyName><ns10:PostalAddress xsi:type="ns10:AddressType"><cbc:StreetName>Street0</cbc:StreetName><cbc:BuildingNumber>1</cbc:BuildingNumber><cbc:CityName>City0</cbc:CityName><cbc:PostalZone>12345</cbc:PostalZone></ns10:PostalAddress><ns10:Contact xsi:type="ns10:ContactType"><cbc:ID>KS_12366</cbc:ID><cbc:ElectronicMail/></ns10:Contact><ns11:AccountCategory>KD</ns11:AccountCategory><ns11:AccountClass>P</ns11:AccountClass><ns11:ParentAccountNumber><cbc:ID>555</cbc:ID></ns11:ParentAccountNumber><ns11:BankAccountNumber>1234</ns11:BankAccountNumber><ns11:Role><ns11:Person><cbc:FirstName>Friedrich</cbc:FirstName><cbc:FamilyName>Müller</cbc:FamilyName><cbc:BirthDate>19700101</cbc:BirthDate><ns11:ContactPhoneNumber><ns11:PhoneNumber>0612387777</ns11:PhoneNumber><ns11:Type>Mobile</ns11:Type></ns11:ContactPhoneNumber></ns11:Person></ns11:Role></ns11:Account></ns0:SearchCustomerResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

So the question is, how come that logstash is spiking to 100% CPU and is this because of below filter? Should it be different or can it be more efficient?

Thanks
Pim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that somebody used GREEDIERDATA. This meant it will match on .* \n \r. If grok needs to parse it will get in a massive loop since it will not know when to stop at all and needs to iterate the complete entry all the time